# progress bar dont work with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, uiprogressview

add UIProgressView with StoryBoard,and set it as the progress bar of ANIHTTPRequet
Do i init the UIProgressView or use function setDownloadProgressDelegate: correctly?
TIA!

```
    @interface xyzViewController : UIViewController {
               ASINetworkQueue *networkQueue;
               BOOL failed;

               ASIHTTPRequest *request;
               NSOperationQueue *queue;
    }
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressBar;
```

//

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
             [super viewDidLoad];
             progressBar = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
             [progressBar setProgress:0.0 animated:YES];
      }
```

//

```
    -(IBAction) downloadStart{

           if (!networkQueue) {
                 networkQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init]; 
           }
           failed = NO;

           [networkQueue reset];
           [networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(imageFetchComplete:)];
           [networkQueue setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(imageFetchFailed:)];
           [networkQueue setShowAccurateProgress: YES];
           [networkQueue setDelegate:self];


           request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/tests/images/large-image.jpg"]];
           [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.png"]];
           [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressBar];
           [request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"request1" forKey:@"name"]];
           [networkQueue addOperation:request];

           [networkQueue go];

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure your IBOutlet is connected properly in IB, if that's the case remove this line:

`progressBar = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];`

...and configure the bar appearance in IB

- make sure you synthesize the property `@synthesize progressBar;`

PS.

- it is better to use 'weak' property for IBOutlets
- if you plan to use ASIHTTPRequest library extensively, it is a good idea to use some other solution. See [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/): `Please note that I am no longer working on this library - you may want to consider using something else for new projects. :)`

Comment: Thanks.The solution is remove the line you figure out.This seems to init it twice(IB help us init once).And i'm trying to move to another library.[UIDownloadBar](https://github.com/sakrist/UIDownloadBar) is much easier to extend